# How to open Android Logcat tool instead of Run tool on running a Flutter app through IDE?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, intellij-idea

Each time I run my app using the green color Play button in the IDE, `Run` tool window opens up automatically, but I want the `Logcat` window to popup instead. How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 26):

You need to use Android run configuration, which has an option to open Logcat automatically on start:
[image]

Comment: Thanks but these options are not available on Flutter module.

Comment: Thanks, i love it for native android development